# Backbone.js with a 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, esri

I am thinking of using Backbone.js for a new application I am developing.  My application is a web mapping application using the ESRI Javascript API and the data is in ESRI Feature Services.

I have been looking at the documentation and tutorials for Backbone.js, but I can't figure out how I would create a model that can retrieve or edit data from an ESRI Feature Service.

How can I make my model retrieve and edit data in a specific way so that is using the methods required by this 3rd party API instead of the traditional HTTP GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the Model.sync, [take a look at the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync)